# How to create common header for all activity with click event in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody tell How to create common header for all activity with click event in android.I have heade button,title,button with click event available.I want use header with common for all activity can anybody tell how to do

`Is it possible to create common code for click activity also`?

Thanks

Comment: create `Header.xml` and `<include>`  it to any layout

Comment: @Simple Plan for click event code also want to common in all activity

Comment: yes it is possible.for the common click that you  have to create a Base activity and write a onClick() in it and extend BaseActivity to all other Activty.
in other Activity's onClick menthod overeide the super.onClick()

Comment: @GovindRathod can you provide some sample code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create one activity with header and content fragment. And change only fragment.